# systemd-modules-load failed to start

Tags: server, systemd

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 server version with my customized kernel.
When booting, I see `systemd-modules-load` failed to start.

`journalctl -xe` error as below

```
-- Unit systemd-modules-load.service has begun starting up.
Jan 28 23:08:08 ubuntu systemd-modules-load[1278]: Failed to find module 'iscsi_tcp'
Jan 28 23:08:08 ubuntu systemd-modules-load[1278]: Failed to find module 'ib_iser'
Jan 28 23:08:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 28 23:08:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
```

As the log mentioned, `iscsi_tcp` and `ib_iser` are failing to be loaded.
However I cannot find where `iscsi_tcp` and `ib_iser` are defined.

`man modules-load.d` list below 3 paths:

```
   /etc/modules-load.d/*.conf
   /run/modules-load.d/*.conf
   /usr/lib/modules-load.d/*.conf
```

The existing one is `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`, and it's empty. Where are `iscsi_tcp` and `ib_iser` defined?

Comment: For any other getting here but `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` showing problem with [tty0tty](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty) null modem emulator, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/588806/349837) is a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to edit `/lib/modules-load.d/open-iscsi.conf`:

```
nano /lib/modules-load.d/open-iscsi.conf
```

change from `ib_iser` to `#ib_iser`

<kbd>F3</kbd> key followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save change,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano

To start services ...

```
systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
```

To check ...

```
systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
```