# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules at Boot on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, raspberrypi

I have installed `ubuntu-18.04.4-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img` on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.  I have no problem to login, but there is a message during bootup the Pi3B+:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?  Thanks.

[image: output]

Comment: When I ran "sudo systemctl status", 
State: degraded
 Jobs: 0 queued
 Failed: 1 units
It didn't state which unit is failed.

Comment: When I ran "sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service", I got

Comment: Please update an answer with `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` output. Comment doesn't seem to provide enough characters for this.

Comment: My question is whether we need 'ib_iser' module, can I ignore it or remove it in open-iscsi.conf?

Comment: It's not even installed accordingly to message. This js why it fails. Check solution from this link  https://askubuntu.com/questions/877245/systemd-modules-load-failed-to-start

Comment: To my knowledge this module is not mandatory

Comment: Thanks @user3417815.  I followed your link to change #ib_iser, now I don't see the Failed message any more.  Do you know what ib_iser for?  Can I get it from somewhere?  I don't want to miss out something.

Comment: this module is an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI_Extensions_for_RDMA , it's not needed on all kernels, only for specific infiniband devices. See this bug on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-iscsi/+bug/1833586 . Discussion confirms that iser_ib may be unavailable for regular kernels.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem @user3417815.  We don't use SCSI in our project, not for Raspberry Pi kernel.